# Delphi 11 TClientSocket can't connect to localhost, Windows socket error : 10049

Tags: sockets, delphi, tclientsocket

So i did this tutorial exactly the same and im getting the Windows socket error: 10049. This is the tutiroal: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/Chat_Room_Socket_(Delphi)
What is the problem here?

Comment: At the line "ClientSocket1.Address:='127.0.0.1';" I also tried "ClientSocket1.Address:='localhost';"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions are expected to be self-contained.  External links can and do break over time. Please [edit] your question to show the relevent code you are actually working with. In any case, you should be using the `ClientSocket1.Host` property instead of `ClientSocket1.Address` (you can't assign `'localhost'` to the `Address`, only an IP will work there). On the client side, the error you are seeing can only come from the `Host`/`Address` being set to an invalid hostname/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is that you are stil using port 0 (default values for both TClientSocket and TServerSocket components).

You should change the port number of both client and server component to be something else than 0. I recommend using ports greater than 1024 in order to avoid using reserved ports.

In fact you might want to consider checking [IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) to make sure the port you will be using isn't registered to another application or service.

PS: Embarcadero should have provided information about the need to change port number used in their example.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

or the port is correct, however, during your testing your system on another computer on your LAN, you deleted the client host property and entered you WAN IP in the address property...
then, wishing to return to using the host name instead of the address, you mistakenly entered your host name in the address property field instead of the host property field.  duh!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35687578)